# Page does not load when instantiating a variable in construct

Tags: php, performance, function, model-view-controller, constructor

Here is my code:

**this works**:

```
<?php

private $controller;

public function __construct() {   
}

public function randomFunc() {
    $this->controller = new Controller();
    return $this->controller;
}

?>
```

**does not work**:

```
<?php

private $controller;

public function __construct() {
    $this->controller = new Controller();   
}

public function randomFunc() {
    return $this->controller;
}

?>
```

as you can see, when I assign `$controller = new Controller()` in function, it works but when i do it in construct, it does not work. how come? thanks

Comment: post your full code that includes the class and any include/require you're using.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is pretty much the full code. i'm using mvc so the require is coming from the file before it gets to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of recursion in constructor. You can make something like that for singleton:

```
protected function __construct() {}

public static function getInstance()
{
    return new Controller();
}
```

Comment: can you pls explain what that mean and what im doing wrong? sorry im new to this.

Comment: So you have a variable who initiated in constructor. But initiated as object of yourself. With variable as an object of yourself. With variable as object of yourself. ... Loop :)

Comment: oh i see, thanks! but i can also add `$this->controller = new Controller();` in every function right?

Comment: Stop. Do you declare it in class Controller? If yes, Controller::getInstance() will return you the object of class Controller. And you don't need the object of class Controller in the object of class Controller :) You can just use $this. If no - you can do it via $this->controller = new Controller();

Comment: what do u mean?